# IdeaBlade - Unable to initialize EntityManager. Could not find a part of the path c:\xxx\bin;64bit

Tags: entity-framework, devforce

Am trying to run my webapi application on IISExpress 64 bit. (because my application runs on 64 bit). When i run it i ended up with the below error.

> Unable to initialize EntityManager. Could not find a part of the path
>   c:\xxx\bin;64bit

We are using IdeaBlade entity framework. 
Please help!!

Thanks,
Kannan.

Comment: DevForce assemblies are built for "Any CPU" and we haven't see any problems when specifically targeting 64 bit.  The error you're seeing likely occurs when DF does its probing, which by default here should be using the AppDomain.RelativeSearchPath.   The path you show is invalid - have you specified DF probe assemblies, defined a probing element in the web.config, or otherwise specified this path somewhere?